# AEAD Decryption with OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I have the following code to decrypt some AEAD encrypted password:

```c
int aead_decrypt(char *cipher_password, int len_cipher_password, char *tag, char *key, char *iv, int len_iv, char **plaintext_password) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    // Cipher_password len always greater or equal to plaintext
    *plaintext_password = (unsigned char *)malloc(len_cipher_password);
    if(*plaintext_password == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failure\n");
        free(*plaintext_password);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new() failure\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptInit_ex() failure\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptInit_ex() failure\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, *plaintext_password, &len, cipher_password, len_cipher_password)) {
        //if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, *plaintext_password, &len, padded_cipher_password, len_padded_cipher_password)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptUpdate() failure\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if(1!=EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, *plaintext_password+len, &len)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex() failure\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        return -1;
    }

    plaintext_len += len;
    (*plaintext_password)[plaintext_len] = '\0';
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 1;
}
```

My problem is that the `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()` function always fail but without printing any errors. 
My `plaintext_password` comes out decrypted but with 16 bytes of garbage at the end because the `EVP_DecryptUpdate()` function doesn't return the good `plaintext_password_len`. 
I thought at first it was because of padding, my cipher_password is often 24-25 bytes long, so i tried adding some as we can see in the different comments but it did not worked out. 
(Also i know i pass some parameters i don't use but that's not what's important here).
I don't know where the problem could be and i'm not that familiar with the OpenSSL library.

Comment: I assume the problem is that _no authentication_ is actually implemented in the current code. For this, the code `if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag)) {...}` must first be commented in and _the tag determined during encryption_ must be used. Then, if the authentication is successful, `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` is also executed successfully. In contrast to authentication, the use of aditional authenticated data (AAD) is optional, s. [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Decryption_using_GCM_mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my example the data is encrypted with an empty tag (""). Is setting the tag necessary then ?

Comment: In general, the tag is generated _automatically_ during encryption. If the tag is empty, I would suspect an issue during encryption. Do you confuse the tag with the additional authenticated data (AAD)? These are optional, i.e. there is no need to set them. [Here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Encryption_using_GCM_mode) you can find an OpenSSL-code for encryption with AES-GCM, which also shows the correct use of tag and AAD. Also check if the used OpenSSL version already supports AES-GCM (to my knowledge from 1.0.1 onwards).

Comment: Oh, i see. But where is the tag data in the cipher data ? In my example the tag size is the default one which is 16 bytes (i think). Is it appended at the end ? That would fix the problem as i would be able to authenticate my data

Comment: Never mind, got it thanks for your answers !

Comment: Fine, you already solved the problem. For the sake of completeness: It often depends on the language. In the linked gcm_encrypt-method of the C-code, it is explicitly determined. In Java, for example, it is appended to the ciphertext during encryption. For the tag size a number of values are specified, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26787), it can generally be adjusted  for the most languages and is 16 bytes by default.

Comment: Also see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, i was actually confusing aad and tag values. In Authenticated encryption the tag value is always generated (can't be null). In my example it was the default size: 16 bytes. Tag value is then appended to the cipher data. You can use it to authenticate your decrypted data.

Here is my fixed code:

```
int aead_decrypt(char *cipher_password, int len_cipher_password, char *key, char *iv, int len_iv, char **plaintext_password) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    // The tag is appended at the end of the cipher data
    int tag_offset = len_cipher_password-16;

    // Cipher_password len always greater or equal to plaintext
    *plaintext_password = (unsigned char *)malloc(len_cipher_password);
    if(*plaintext_password == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failure\n");
            free(*plaintext_password);
            return -1;
    }

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptInit_ex() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptInit_ex() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -1;
    }

    // Set the expected tag value for authenticated data
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, cipher_password+tag_offset)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -1;
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, *plaintext_password, &len, cipher_password, tag_offset)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptUpdate() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return -1;
    }

    plaintext_len = len;

    if(1!=EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, *plaintext_password+len, &len)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex() failure\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    }

    plaintext_len += len;
    (*plaintext_password)[plaintext_len] = '\0';
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 1;}
```